# Combining two columns & doing this for any future rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to create a formula to combine two columns but also automatically  do this for subsequent items added to the list automatically. The answers are responses from a Google Form and when the form is submitted I would like the next item of the list to automatically combine the columns without needing to drag down the formula.

```
=CONCATENATE(I2:I," ",J2:J)
```

I've found a few solutions that list the items individually but want the two columns combined and then to continue for each subsequent item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula, or see [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FcqM8RNEyEwMiHUErqmTRGjjLYjcr00raMxgtKVrUvs/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(I2:I="",,I2:I&" "&J2:J))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(I2:I&" "&J2:J)
```

or if you mind empty space in empty cell use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(I2:I&" "&J2:J))
```

Comment: The second formula your suggested has worked best! Thank you